# how to retrieve data from mysql table while clicking on anchor tag

Tags: java

In my first JSP page my database table rows are displayed in separate articles.

In these articles i have anchor tags which are a column of my table in mysql(Title). I want to click the anchor tag and then in second jsp page i want the row of mysql table to be displayed that has the same Title in the anchor tag.

In my first JSP page, i have an anchor tag under inside try{}catch() that displays Title column from mysql table. i want when i click on it it should go to second jsp page and display the table row of mysql table that has same Title.

Can you help?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
    <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
    <%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement" %>
    <%
    String id = request.getParameter("userid");
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection con =null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">
html,
body{
height:100%;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
background:white;
font-family:'Lora', serif;
min-height:100%;
}
ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: white;
width:100%;
 border:1px solid grey;
}
li{
float: right;

}
li a{
display: block;
color: #4682B4;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px 22px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active){
background-color: white;
}
header{
font-family:serif;
margin-bottom:0;
background:#4682B4;
height:70px;
color:white;
text-align:center;
name:title;
}
article{
width:300px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
border: 1px solid grey;
float:left;
margin:10px;
}
.image-wrapper{
width:300px;
float:left;
padding-right:25px;
padding-bottom:10px;
}
.image-wrapper img{
width:100%;
}
.article-meta{
font-family:sans-serif;
color:#aaa;
font-size:12px;
}
p{
font-size:20px;
color:#4682B4;
text-decoration:none;
}
a{
font-size:20px;
color:#4682B4;
text-decoration:none;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
<img class="myheader" src="C:\Users\zaryab Ahmad\Desktop\ASIO.jpg" style="width:10%; height:10%">
<li><a class="active" href="NewPost.jsp">NewPost</a></li>
<li><a href="Contacts.jsp">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="Opportunity.jsp">Opportunity</a></li>
<li><a href="Aboutus.jsp">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="Projects.jsp">Projects</a></li>
<li><a href="Retrieve.jsp">Latest News</a></li>
<li><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li>
</ul>



<h1>retreive</h1>   
<%
try{
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/asio","root","");
     st = con.createStatement();
    String query = "Select * from posts";
    rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next()){
        %>

    <article>
<header><%=rs.getString("Title") %></header>

<div class="image-wrapper">
<img src="C:\Users\zaryab Ahmad\Desktop\ASIO.jpg"">
<span>Image source : the Web</span>
</div>

<p><a href="./Fulldescpost" method="get"><%=rs.getString("Title")%></a>
</p>
<input type="text" name="discription" value="<%=rs.getString("Title")%>">
</article>      
        <%
    }
    con.close();
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
%>

</body>
</html>

this is my second jsp page
in this page i want to display row from mysql table that has a column called Title which is the same in anchor tag in first page. i want the relevent row to be displayed.

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

     <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
    <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
    <%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement" %>
    <%
    String id = request.getParameter("userid");

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection con =null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>

html,
body{
height:100%;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
background:white;
font-family:'Lora', serif;
min-height:100%;
}

header{
font-family:serif;
margin-bottom:0;
background:#4682B4;
width:100%;
height:70px;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<%
try{
    String title1 = request.getParameter("discription");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/asio","root","");
     st = con.createStatement();
    String query ="Select * from posts where Title='"+title1+"'";
    rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next()){
        %>
<!..i have problem in here..>
<header><%=rs.getString("Title") %></header>

<section class="w3-container w3-center w3-content">
<img class="mySlides" src="C:\Users\zaryab Ahmad\Desktop\asio.jpeg" style="width:100%">
<img class="mySlides" src="C:\Users\zaryab Ahmad\Desktop\asio1.jpg" style="width:100%">
<img class="mySlides" src="C:\Users\zaryab Ahmad\Desktop\wfp.jpg" style="width:100%">

</section>

<script>
var myIndex=0;
carousel();

function carousel(){
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    //var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        x[i].style.display = "none";

    }
    myIndex++;
    if(myIndex > x.length){myIndex=1}
    x[myIndex-1].style.display="block";
    setTimeout(carousel , 3000);
}
</script>

<p>this is the full paragraph of the post.</p>
    <%
    }
    con.close();
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
%>

</body>
</html>
```